# Top border not extending full width on iPad?

Tags: html, css, ipad

My page's body has a 15px border on the top.

On the iPad, this border is cut off, leaving white space on the right-hand side.

Screenshot - http://cl.ly/image/0m1V3T2D3A0j

How can I make sure the border extends to the right edge of the viewport on the iPad? I have tried adding width: 100% to the body element, as well as a few other tweaks, and I can't resolve the issue.

Comment: maybe `max-width: 1024px;`? Not exactly a good fix, but if you can set this CSS to 'only iPad' it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your body content is too wide for the iPad. #all-logos is 1157px wide - iPad resolution is 1024 × 768. That said, if you look at it on an iPad 3, with resolution 2048 × 1536, I would guess it'll work.

You might want to add some conditional formatting for mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks. Our client wanted it to be that wide. Not sure why. I would resize the picture frames to be narrower, but they're built using CSS rollovers unfortunately.

Comment: All good. I removed the border and instead added a min-width to a 15px div at the top of the body. That should do the trick.